# I can't seem to open this .jar file. Can someone make sense out of my error message?

Tags: terminal, mac, java

I'm trying to set up a modded minecraft server on my Mac.

I am on Mojave 10.14.6 and I have Java SE Oracle JDK 15.0.1 installed.

Each time I attempt to open the file `forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854-universal.jar` I get prompted  with a warning "The Java JAR file "`forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854-universal.jar`" could not be launched." [image]

I also tried opening it with Terminal, relocating the directory and inputting `java -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854-universal.jar` but here, i got the error back.[image]

Unfortunately, I am unable to read code. I've done my researched and found multiple others with the same problem but they all had to do with their `MANIFEST.MF` file, I don't believe that is my case here, from the minimal info I could make out of the error message, I was wondering if anyone can help me find out what is the problem and how I can fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Copy and paste the error code, instead of including a screenshot.

Comment: Yes pleas with my eyesight I can't read the text so I can't help you

Answer (score 1):

It works, I just have to update my java. sigh.